# Add nofollow tag to External links in WordPress using PHP

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I want to write a PHP code for WordPress that does the below in the Gutenberg Block Editor. Changes should be made to the content before it is saved in the database.

When Publish or Update button is clicked in WordPress, I want the links to be updated in the following way:

1. Take the links and check if its internal or external.
2. If its external, add the `nofollow` attribute to `rel=""`. Note `rel=""` might already have a value like `rel="noopener"`. If it has a value then we must add it like this `rel="noopener nofollow"`.
3. Skip adding the `nofollow` tag if the `dofollow` tag or `nofollow` is already present.
4. If `target=""` value is not set, then set `target="_blank"`.

I have the following code but it messes up my links.

```
add_filter('content_save_pre', 'modify_links_before_saving', 10, 1);

function modify_links_before_saving($content) {
    $site_url = get_site_url();
    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);  // Suppress errors (due to HTML5 tags etc.)
    $dom->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($content, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));
    libxml_clear_errors();

    $links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
    foreach ($links as $link) {
        // Check if the link is external
        $href = $link->getAttribute('href');
        if (strpos($href, $site_url) === false) {  // External link
            // Add 'nofollow' to 'rel' attribute
            $rel = $link->getAttribute('rel');
            if (!empty($rel)) {
                $rel .= ' nofollow';
            } else {
                $rel = 'nofollow';
            }
            $link->setAttribute('rel', $rel);
        }

        // Add 'target="_blank"' if not already set
        $target = $link->getAttribute('target');
        if (empty($target)) {
            $link->setAttribute('target', '_blank');
        }
    }

    $html = $dom->saveHTML();
    return $html;
}
```

When I add the above code in codesnippets and save a post

A post that looks like this

```
<!-- wp:paragraph -->
<p><a href="http://google.com">External Link</a></p>
<!-- /wp:paragraph -->

<!-- wp:paragraph -->
<p><a href="http://microsoft.com" rel="noopener">No Opener</a></p>
<!-- /wp:paragraph -->

<!-- wp:paragraph -->
<p><a href="http://yahoo.com" rel="dofollow">dofollow</a></p>
<!-- /wp:paragraph -->
```

Now looks like this

```
<!-- wp:paragraph -->
<p><a href="%5C%22//google.com%5C%22%5C%22" rel="&quot;nofollow nofollow noopener" noopener="" target="&quot;_blank&quot;">External Link</a></p>
<!-- /wp:paragraph -->

<!-- wp:paragraph -->
<p><a href="%5C%22//microsoft.com%5C%22%5C%22" rel="&quot;&quot;noopener&quot; nofollow noopener" nofollow="" noopener="" target="&quot;_blank&quot;">No Opener</a></p>
<!-- /wp:paragraph -->

<!-- wp:paragraph -->
<p><a href="%5C%22//yahoo.com%5C%22%5C%22" rel="&quot;&quot;dofollow&quot; nofollow noopener" nofollow="" noopener="" target="&quot;_blank&quot;">dofollow</a></p>
<!-- /wp:paragraph -->
```

This seems like a simple straightforward problem but it seems too complicated to solve. There are many answers on stackoverflow that gives me similar issues or replace the rel attribute completely. But it doesn't work for the Gutenberg Block Editor.

Comment: How are you able to see the latter output? Your output seems OK.

Comment: When I put the first text in a WordPress Post and click Save, I get the latter output.